# What is this pyramid-like structure in the Underground Jungle?

Tags: terraria

I was looking around in the Underground Jungle, and I saw this:

[image: screenshot]

It looks like a pyramid, but it's deep underground! I also remember reading that there can't be a pyramid **and** a living tree in the same world, and there's a living tree in my world. (Pyramids are supposed to spawn in deserts, too.)

What is this? I died shortly after (I only had an Ice Boomerang, Trident, and Musket to fight with, and Meteor Armor), and it's quite hard to mine out that block and see what it is while being attacked by jungle enemies. It might not even be possible to mine with the Nightmare Pickaxe.

Comment: Pyramids and living trees can be generated in the same world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a new type of dungeon in the underground jungle. You fight the [Golem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem) there at the [Lihzahrd Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Altar).

You can break the blocks once you kill the Golem.
You can't kill the Golem till hardmode is activated.

Comment: Does this generate in every jungle now, or is it an optional thing that depends on world gen? I've been exploring my jungle for more bees to kill and haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @Fambida the [Lihzahrd Temple](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Temple) generates in the jungle after you defeat [Plantera](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera)

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, this is a Jungle Temple. It can be entered by unlocking the door with a Jungle Key, obtained in Hardmode by killing Plantera. The Key itself will always drop when Plantera is killed.

The Lihzard Bricks it is made of, as well as the Lihzard Altar inside, can only be destroyed by a tool with over 200% pickaxe power.

Hence, to relocate the Altar, the Golem must be fought. There is a 12.5% chance (Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem ) that the Golem will drop the Picksaw, which has 210% pickaxe power -- the strongest in Terraria and enough to break the Lihzard Altar. This can be beneficial for relocating the Altar to a player-made arena.

Answer (score 2):

This is Lihzard temple, where Golem can be fought with Lihzard Power Cells at a Lihzard altar. If you defeat Plantera, it will drop a temple key. I would recommend getting in with dynamite on the door, as it will not break Lihzard bricks. The temple key should be saved to make biome keys. See Biome Chest on Terraria Wiki :P

Answer (score 1):

This is a Lihzahrd Temple. You have to defeat Plantera, who will drop the key to enter the temple.

Answer (score 0):

[Pyramid](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pyramid) are located in the desert.

This is the [Jungle temple](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_temple) which you can unlock with a key, but only on hardmode.

By experience, it seems the blocks can't be mine (at least not in normal mode as I am)

Answer (score -1):

Note that in the Lihzahrd temple you can't get through the entrance without the key or explosives.Just throw the explosive on the door to get through.I got in in Pre hard mode and pre-Plantera.Though you need the picksaw from Golem to mine the Lihzahrd blocks.[image]

Comment: The key from Plantera.

Comment: I did it on IOS

Comment: You find the Lihzahrd power cell in chests or you make it by 10 glass, 25 fallen stars and 10 adamantite bars. But you'll still be able to fight Golem before hard mode but the chances are you'll die

Comment: Get the power cell from the chests in the Temple. Chances are there are two.